# Storing oledb connection string in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, oledb

I have read several Stackoverflow suggestions and ways to store a connection string in `web.config`.

However I have an issue how to store my connection string and reference it.

My connection string looks like this

```
 connString =  string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"", fileName);
```

I can't quite add this to my connection string

```
<add name="ExcelConnection" 
     connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\""/>
```

Isn't quite working.

How do I secure my application by using the `web.config` to store connection strings?

Edit:

C# code that reads it

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"", fileName);

DataSet data = new DataSet();

try
{
    foreach (var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString))
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);

            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            data.Tables.Add(dataTable);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
}
```

Comment: Explain what is not working.

Comment: because it's not real connection string ... put a real `Data Source` instead `{0}`

Comment: It is just a string. You read it back from the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_key_] and then use your string.Format to add the filename

Comment: Please edit your question to add the c# code that reads the config and attempts to use it.

Comment: @JohnWu I did add the edit

Comment: @Steve Well the syntax is incorrect in the web.config

Comment: @Selvin The real Data Source is a file path to read a file

Comment: Store it with _"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"_ Just replace the double quotes in the middle with a single quote, leave the start and end double quotes, finally remove the \ before the single quote

Comment: @Steve Thanks. How will I then reference it in my code?

Comment: _ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExcelConnection"].ConnectionString_

Comment: @Steve So my connection string looks like  **<add name="ExcelConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"/>**                and  I am calling it this way  **string connectionString = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExcelConnection"].ConnectionString, fileName);** I am getting Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 130